# Network not starting up on boot

Tags: networking

Basically my network won't start. Can't use wired connections.

To make it a further brain-scratcher, when booting into recovery, and using the network console, the network comes up and works. Outside of recovery nothing.

As far as I can tell no settings changed between powering off and on since last time it worked, except for an automatic kernel upgrade. Using an older kernel does not seem to help.

Also this hardware configuration worked perfectly fine for over a year with kernel upgrades and all. Network was always automatic.

Information for follow up questions...

Network manager is running.

Strangely enough, my network interface was never started, nor was DHCP. Where in the configuration can I find this?

To manually resolve the problem:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo /etc/dhclient
```

What could have happened in my config to not make this work automatically.

Info gathered:

```
> lspci | grep net
> 6:00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
```

Contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

After adding

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

the eth0 interface comes up, but the `dhclient` does not.

--

The problem re-occurred when waking up from sleep.

Comment: Is Network Manager running?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are likely missing the line for this in the interfaces file. Open `/etc/network/interfaces` and check if there is a line for `eth0` If not add the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

This will add the `eth0` interface - and use DHCP on boot and wakeup.

If you're still not getting DHCP response you may also need to add dhcp back into defaults:

`sudo update-rc.d dhcp3-server defaults`

Comment: Not working. After a sleep/resume `sudo dhclient` was still required. The card was up and running though.

Comment: Ok, so just rebooted, network came up automatically. Thanks Marco!

Comment: To make this answer work, I had to insert the `auto eth0` stanza above the 'auto lo' that was already there.

Comment: this should work but don't know why its not working for me

Comment: This answer did not solve my issue (Ubuntu 15.04, running in VM). I have to either do `/etc/init.d/network restart` or `dhclient eth0` after booting, before eth0 gets its IP address from (bridged) interface.

Comment: Warning: in my case it actually prevented me from booting. It's nasty.

Comment: @Dualinity which version of ubuntu were you using? Might help others.

Answer (score 1):

What does `ifconfig -a` show when it's not working? Is there an `eth0`? If it's not, I'd check the modules blacklists `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist*`. I would have expected the recovery console to honour these though so moving on...

If you do have an interface, it could be some dodgy config inside network-manager. Recovery mode just uses some defaults IIRC so I'd open up the network settings (right click the applet, click edit connections) and check a few things:

- Connect Automatically is checked
- You have a MAC address
- MTU is automatic
- 802.1x security is disabled
- IPv4 is set to Automatic (DHCP)
- Require IPv4 is checked
- There should be no special routes
- IPv6 is set to ignore

If `ifconfig -a` isn't showing an `eth0` device, it could be something bizarrely hardware specific. What does `lspci | grep net` show? If nothing, do you know what the network chipset is?

Comment: ifconfig only shows lo. blacklist only has pcspkr. Network settings interface does nothing. I tried adding a connection the way you described it.

Comment: When network is working, there is no entry in the network connections under wired at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could `pm-powersave` be the cause of your problem? My answer to [How to connect wirelessly in a cafe with 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65001/how-to-connect-wirelessly-in-a-cafe-with-11-04/65606#65606) might apply

Answer (score -2):

I've installed dhcpcd5 and it worked for me.

sudo apt-get install dhcpcd5

Comment: This wont fix the lack of networking on a desktop machine.