# Waiting for network configuration message at boot, then blank screen

Tags: networking, 11.10, dhcp

When I boot (11.10), I get the message that it's "waiting for network configuration" and then the same, but "60 seconds longer" and then finially it "boots" but to a black screen. No cursor, just black. It doesn't seem to respond to anything.

I am able to boot with the "recovery" kernel and do anything you can normally do there. Except "root prompt with networking" doesn't actually have networking. ifconfig returns nothing. iwconfig says that eth0 and lo are uninitialized. I was going to load the networking kernel module, but I don't know which one to load. I am also able to boot with a live cd (technically a usb drive) and it boots fast with no messages/errors and networking works.

The networking adapter is from a Gigabyte GA-M57SLI-S4 motherboard.

I have read this: ["Waiting for network configuration" adding 3 to 5 minutes to boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63456/waiting-for-network-configuration-adding-3-to-5-minutes-to-boot-time)

This doesn't seem to help my problem.

My /etc/network/interfaces had

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

So I added

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

This solution here: [Network not starting up on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4901/network-not-starting-up-on-boot)
Gives the error that /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server: file does not exist.

Comment: What does your network environment look like? Is there a computer, firewall or router on your network that's providing DHCP service? Are you connected to it? If you answered "NO" to either, you should read `man 5 interfaces`, the whole **INET ADDRESS FAMILY** section. You may need a static address.

Comment: Can you do 'ctrl-alt-f1' and get a text login prompt? Also what edition did you install, stock 11.10 ?

Answer (score 2):

you can find a solution here :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/811441
in the post #24

Comment: Better to just reinstall Ubuntu cleanly.

Comment: i ended up reinstalling ubuntu completely.

Comment: Easy to follow steps can be found here: http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-10-problem-waiting-for-network-configuration-then-black-screen-solution/

Comment: the link above me doesnt work somehow

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was booting into root and deleting the `/var/run/dbus` directory. Hope this helps!