# networking problems

Tags: networking

I run ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop as a small webserver. For many months, everything went prefectly, but when I moved it to an other house with an other internet connection, it started to boot slowly, showing the message "Waiting for network configuration". I know I edited the /etc/network/interfaces, but I can't recall what I have modified. Obviously, I can't get any internet connection.

Here is the /etc/network/interfaces as it is right now:

```
# This file...
# and how to...

# The loopback...
auto lo p2p1
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary...
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet dhcp
```

When I type `ifconfig -a | grep p2p1` I get

```
p2p1        Link encap:Ethernet   HWaddr e8:40:f2:df:1c:a6
```

When I type `lshw -class network` I get

```
*-network DISABLED
description: Ethernet interface
(somme other stuff)
serial e8:40:f2:df:1c:a6
```

Edit: typing `ifconfig` gives only info about the local loopback and nothing about eth0.

Edit 2: Result of `ping -c 3 google.com`

```
PING google.com (74.125.226.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga15s28-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.195): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=28.3ms
64 bytes from lga15s28-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.195): icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=26.7ms
64 bytes from lga15s28-in-f3.1e100.net (74.125.226.195): icmp_req=3 ttl=52 time=28.2ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 recieved, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.713/27.743/28.302/0.754 ms
```

Therefore, I can decuce that there is an internet connection, which is good news. Starting the computer still gives the same error message.

Edit 3: When shutting down, I get this error message (it might be related):

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Edit 4: On startup, I also get

```
Starting configure network device               [fail]
Starting configure virtual network devices      [fail]
```

Typing `ifconfig p2p1` gives

```
p2p1        Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr e8:40:f2:df:1c:a6
            inet addr:192.168.1.102 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::ea40:f2ff:fedf:1ca6/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
            RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 everruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 everruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
            RX bytes:7839 (7.8 KB) TX bytes:1623 (1.6 KB)
```

...but `ifconfig` alone will only give info about the local loopback

Any advise to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of ifconfig?

Comment: Yes, it gives only information about the local loopback, nothing about eth0.

Comment: Have you ever seen eth0 in your ifconfig?

Comment: No, I havent't.

Comment: Okay. Try this.
 sudo dhclient p2p1

and post the output of ping -c 3 google.com

Comment: There it is, hope it helps

Comment: Nice. Can you post the output of ifconfig p2p1?

Comment: Typing dhclient enables the ethernet and I can access the server! But I have to type it after every reboot. Startup is still slow and shows the 3 errors I mentionned in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good! Check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/4901/network-not-starting-up-on-boot?rq=1
@Erigami mentioned something interesting. Try to put 
# The primary...
auto p2p1
iface p2p1 inet dhcp

before the line of # The loopback... in  /etc/network/interfaces