# Wired Connection Stoped working after update

Tags: networking, connection, wired

My desktop is an old DELL that originally ran on Windows XP. Ubuntu 12.04 makes it run like brand new.
After a bunch of updates the wired connections stopped working.

Network Connections reads;

```
Wired Connection 1    Last Used 8 days ago..  
ifupdown (etho)                  never
```

Output of `nm-tool` is as follows:

```
nm-tool.
Network Manager Tool
Device: eth0   [ifupdown (eth0) 
Type: wired
Driver: r8169 
State: connecting (getting IP configuration)
Default: no
HW Address: 6C:FD:B9:3B:BD:4D
Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:
   Speed: 100 Mb
Wired Properties:
  Carrier: on
```

I don't know what update caused this connection to stop working.

Comment: Seems like is a dhcp problem ( _State: connecting (getting IP configuration)_ ). You may check what packages were updated at the files in /var/log/apt directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use these 2 commands.It worked for me.

```
sudo lshw -c network -sanitize​​
sudo modprobe r8169
```

Else refer these links.

[ethernet-not-connecting-on-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400929/ethernet-not-connecting-on-boot)

[no-wired-ethernet-connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118850/no-wired-ethernet-connection)

[Ethernet -not-connecting](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2201556)