# Ethernet Connection Problem, Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu Mate

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi that I am having difficulties with.  It is some kind of networking issue but I lack the terminology to describe it that way so I will keep it as simple as I can and hopefully someone can fill me in on the proper lingo.

I have an intermittent problem connecting to my network.  It is a small office network.  What is happening is this... When everything is groovy I am assigned an IP such as:

192.168.127.35

However, sometimes I get this....

192.168.0.35

Like I said I am not sure what that is called but obviously I am missing the 127 and not in the right place.  Can anyone describe what might be happening and how I can get this to connect consistently?

I am using ifconfig -a to get this information and I have tried restart the network using /etc/init.d/networking restart but the problem persists.

Doing more research and learning that this is perhaps related to:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.127.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

I tried to setup a new default gateway and have playing with this problem but to be honest I am unsure what I am doing... I am guessing I need the above to be fixed in some way?

This is a continuation of this post but I really wanted to refocus it because of this IP specific question.
[Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2, Raspberry Pi 3b, ethernet not automatically connecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895899/ubuntu-mate-16-04-2-raspberry-pi-3b-ethernet-not-automatically-connecting)

Comment: i assigned the ip address or it read from DHCP server ? you can assign a static ip address to your raspberry pi and that ip never change . 
you can do this [https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/] link

Comment: The extraordinary methods that users go to to rename misconfigured interfaces are useless. Persistent naming is here to stay and renaming a problem doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Is Network Manager running on the system? Have you added any settings there? Usually NM will do its job well with no human intervention.

Comment: I ended up using a static ip after finding out which ip that could be and setup my /etc/network/interfaces file to handle that... I will update the post above when I get time.  Dealing with networking in another country with limited language skills is not easy.